# Is there similar chart like MPAndroidChart I can use in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart for my Android Studio project. I am migrating the codes over to Flutter. Is there similar MPAndroidChart or I can use it in Flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google search would provide you with

- Package

  - https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter
- Some Guide material

  - https://medium.com/flutter-io/beautiful-animated-charts-for-flutter-164940780b8c
- Some more helpful thing

  - https://flutterawesome.com/tag/chart/

Answer (score 0):

mp_chart package is what you need

Answer (score 0):

MP chart is also available on https://pub.dev/packages as **MPFlutterChart**.

Here is the link: https://pub.dev/packages/mp_chart